# Find the sum of first 101 terms from $n=1 $ in $\frac{a_n^3}{1-3a_n+3a_n^2}$ where $a_n=\frac{n}{101}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of first 101 terms in $\frac{a_n^3}{1-3a_n+3a_n^2}$ where $a_n=\frac{n}{101}$.

So writing it down,

$$\implies\frac{a_1^3}{1-3a_1+3a_1^2} + \frac{a_2^3}{1-3a_2+3a_2^2}+ \cdots +\frac{a_{101}^3}{1-3a_{101}+3a_{101}^2}$$
Substituting for a,

$$\implies\frac{(\frac{1}{101})^3}{1-3(\frac{1}{101})+3(\frac{1}{101})^2} + \frac{(\frac{2}{101})^3}{1-3(\frac{2}{101})+3(\frac{2}{101})^2}+ \cdots +\frac{(\frac{101}{101})^3}{1-3(\frac{101}{101})+3(\frac{101}{101})^2}$$

The last term is $1$. So,
$$\implies\frac{(\frac{1}{101})^3}{1-3(\frac{1}{101})+3(\frac{1}{101})^2} + \frac{(\frac{2}{101})^3}{1-3(\frac{2}{101})+3(\frac{2}{101})^2}+ \cdots +1$$

Looking at the terms it seems the value increases as $n$ increases. Then $1$ is the highest value in the series. At $n=\frac{101}2$ I found that $$\frac{(\frac{101}{2})^3}{1-3(\frac{101}{2})+3(\frac{101}{2})^2}=\frac12$$
So if the first term is almost $o$, the middle term is $\frac12$ and last term is $1$, I'm thinking it's a linear series which means, I'm guessing, the sum is $\frac{101}2=50.5$

What's the answer and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{1-3x+3x^2}=\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^3+x^3}$, we have $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$. Thus the sum is $\sum_{n=1}^{101}f(\frac{n}{101})=\sum_{n=1}^{50}(f(\frac{n}{101})+f(\frac{101-n}{101}))+f(1)=51.$

Comment: I just wanted to write the same, so I have to admit: good answer. ;-)

Comment: Wow. I totally missed that cubic identity. Thanks!